# OpenCV convert from B/W to RGB

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

i have converted an image from RGB to B/W then i want to convert it back to RGB but i have a problem on that:

my code:

```
             int width=zoomedImage->width;
             int height=zoomedImage->height;
             TempImage=cvCreateImage(cvSize(width,height),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
             cvCvtColor(zoomedImage, TempImage,CV_RGB2GRAY);
             cvThreshold( TempImage, TempImage,128,256,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
             cvCvtColor( TempImage,zoomedImage,CV_GRAY2RGB);
             this->pictureBox1->Image=(gcnew 
System::Drawing::Bitmap(zoomedImage->width,zoomedImage->height,zoomedImage->widthStep, 
System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,(System::IntPtr)zoomedImage->imageData));
```

here i'm displaying zoomedImage as a B/W image,in another action i want to display zoomedImage as an RGB image the major problem here is that i can't change the image that will be draw as another parts of my code is depending on this sequence, i wrote that in the other action:

```
  cvCvtColor( TempImage,zoomedImage,CV_GRAY2RGB);
this->pictureBox1->Image=(gcnew 
System::Drawing::Bitmap(zoomedImage->width,zoomedImage->height,zoomedImage->widthStep, 
System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,(System::IntPtr)zoomedImage->imageData));
```

but zoomedImage still dispalyed as B/W, i heared that when a true color image is converted to gray it can't be returned again as a true color image, so what does CV_GRAY2RGB do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved my problem as following:

Convert Original image to B/W

```
             int width=zoomedImage->width;
             int height=zoomedImage->height;
             ColorSaver=cvCreateImage(cvSize(width,height),zoomedImage->depth,zoomedImage->nChannels);
             ColorSaver=cvCloneImage(zoomedImage);
             TempImage=cvCreateImage(cvSize(width,height),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
             cvCvtColor(zoomedImage, TempImage,CV_RGB2GRAY);
             cvThreshold( TempImage, TempImage,128,256,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
             cvCvtColor( TempImage,zoomedImage,CV_GRAY2RGB);
             this->pictureBox1->Image=(gcnew
```

System::Drawing::Bitmap(zoomedImage->width,zoomedImage->height,zoomedImage->widthStep, 
System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,(System::IntPtr)zoomedImage->imageData));

return back the original image to RGB:

```
zoomedImage=cvCloneImage(ColorSaver);
this->pictureBox1->Image=(gcnew 
System::Drawing::Bitmap( zoomedImage->width, zoomedImage->height, zoomedImage->widthStep, 
System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,(System::IntPtr) zoomedImage->imageData));
```

Answer (score 5):

When you convert an RGB image to a gray level image, color information is lost, and this information cannot be recovered fom the gray level image again.

When you try to convert B/W image to RGB you only make a 3 channel image, but all channels contain the same intensity data. Hence you get a gray level image with 3 channels. Nothing more.

Comment: You should maintain the original color image. Otherwise it is naturally impossible to get color information from a gray level image. Consider this: in the original image you have r=20, g = 50, b = 80 for a pixel. When you convert this image to gray level you get a single intensity value 50 lets say. When you then convert the image back to rgb, what you get is r = 50, g = 50, b = 50. Which is completely different from the original values. As you can see from this example, if you do not maintain the original color information somewhere, you cannot recover color info from a gray level image.

Comment: i tried that: ColorSaver=cvCreateImage(cvSize(width,height),zoomedImage->depth,zoomedImage->nChannels);
                 ColorSaver=cvCloneImage(zoomedImage);

Comment: Actually yo can use the original `zoomedImage`, nothing more is required. Just delete the B/W to RGB conversion part.

Comment: @Eslam, trying to get back the color is like trying to unscramble an egg. Never going to happen.

Comment: @ViZier how can i delete B/W to RGB conversion part, i need it !

Comment: @Mark Ransom if i cloned the zoomedImage to another image before i conver it to B/W,i'll able to save the color

Comment: I mean just comment out this line : `cvCvtColor( TempImage,zoomedImage,CV_GRAY2RGB);`

Comment: but at this state the zoomedImage that will be displayed is the B/W Version not the true color

Comment: In the first part of your code, use TempImage for drawing, and do not modify zoomedImage. Then in the second part you will have unmodified (colored) zoomed image.

Comment: i want to display zoomedImage as a true color image

Comment: if i changed the image that will be drawn i'll have problems with another parts of my code